# Laravel sending email with shared hosting with cpanel - fails

Tags: php, laravel, email, cpanel, shared

I need to send verification mail to any user who registers on my app. My Laravel version is 5.4.36. I am using shared hosting with cpanel.

So I made an email account through cpanel which should send emails. Here are cpanel's recommended settings:

Username:   rutko@mladensblogger.rs
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.mladensblogger.rs

IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server:    mail.mladensblogger.rs

SMTP Port: 465

Here is my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mladensblogger.rs
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=rutko@mladensblogger.rs
MAIL_PASSWORD=myaccountpass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Everything looks fine to me, here is the controller where mail sending is needed:

RegisterController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // ************************** -- RULES -- ***************************

    $rules = [
        'tbEmail' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'tbUser' => 'required|alpha_num|unique:users,user',
        'tbPass' => 'required|min:6',
        'tbPassConfirm' => 'required|same:tbPass',
        'tbNameSurname' => 'required|min:3',
        'tbPhone' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]*$/'
    ];

    // ************************** -- MESSAGES -- ***************************

    $messages = [
        'required' => 'Polje :attribute je obavezno',
        'same' => 'Ponovljena lozinka nije ista kao i lozinka',
        'regex' => ':attribute nije u dozvoljenom formatu',
        'email' => 'Email nije u dobrom formatu',
        'tbPhone.regex' => 'Broj telefona mora biti zapisan brojevima i ne sme sadržati slova',
        'tbUser.regex' => 'Korisničko ime mora početi malim slovom, i ne sme imati razmake',
        'tbNameSurname.min' => 'Ime nije u ispravnom formatu',
        'min' => ':attribute mora imati minimum :min karaktera',
        'unique' => ':attribute je već iskorišćen/a'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);

    $email = $request->get('tbEmail');
    $username = $request->get('tbUser');
    $pass = $request->get('tbPass');
    $passConfirm = $request->get('tbPassConfirm');
    $nameSurname = $request->get('tbNameSurname');
    $phone = $request->get('tbPhone');

    try{
        $user = new User(); // Model for saving the user
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->pass = $pass;
        $user->user = $username;
        $user->name_surname = $nameSurname;
        $user->phone = $phone;

        $result = $user->saveWithRegularUserRole();

        $verify_user = new VerifyUser();
        $result_for_id = $user->getByUserAndPass();
        $verify_user->user_id = $result_for_id->id;
        $verify_user->token = str_random(40);
        $verify_user->create();

        //Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

        if($result == 1){
            return redirect()->route('index')->with('success', 'Uspešno ste se registrovali');}
        else{
            return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'Neuspeh pri registraciji, molimo pokušajte opet!');}
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception){
        \Log::error('Error: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Greška pri radu aplikacije, molimo pokušajte ponovo!');
    }


}
```

Here is the VerifyMail

```
class VerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.verifyUser');
    }
}
```

In my view which is returned after storing the user, if everything passes correctly, a success is shown, othervise, error is shown. Basically mail won't send and view shows error, but when I comment the Mail::toline, a success is shown. I have no ideas, and have tried multiple ways to modify the .env file, maybe the controller is making the problem?

Comment: What error do you have? you are logging at `\Log::error('Error: ' . $exception->getMessage());`, so that have something inside `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Here it is:

[2018-08-03 19:22:08] local.ERROR: Error: View [view.name] not found.

Comment: I only now realised that I was trying to send a view which does not exist. I replaced to an existing view but now it still returns a page with error, and error log file is blank (shows no error at the register time)

Comment: Woah, I am actually making some progress. I changed mail driver to "mail" and now it works! Only it sends the mail to spam which kinda bothers me

Comment: When sending from hosting it will almost always land in spam, what you need is something like mailgun they have whitelisted severs, it is also free and would work together with your hosting